# Target next siblings child to get outerheight

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, parent-child, siblings

I'd like to get the height value of the class `.child` in the example below and then use an alert to display the value for troubleshooting.

I have two elements `.first` and `.second` that are siblings, the `.second` element has a child called `.child`

The HTML:

```
<div class="parent">

  <div class="first">Click Me</div>

  <div class="second">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.first {
   width: 60px;
   padding: 8px;
   background: blue;
}

.child {
   height: 1234px;
}
```

The jQuery:

```
$(".first").click(function() {

  var childHeight = $(this).next(".second > .child").outerHeight();

  alert(childHeight);

});
```

The problem seems to be in targeting the child, if I remove the `> .child` from my var it returns the height of `.second`

Here is a JS fiddle with the same code: https://jsfiddle.net/CultureInspired/6dxLp86b/

Comment: I've also tried using find instead of next, as well as nextAll or nextUntil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.next(".second").find(".child")` to get the child element correctly.

This will get the next element and then will find the `.child` element inside that.

```js
$(".first").click(function() {

  var childHeight = $(this).next(".second").find(".child").outerHeight();
  alert(childHeight);

});
```

```css
.first {
  width: 60px;
  padding: 8px;
  background: blue;
}

.child {
  height: 1234px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">

  <div class="first">Click Me</div>

  <div class="second">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly, I could of sworn I tried this method more then once last night, thanks for the help.

Comment: I have to wait 8 minutes :)

Comment: @SamAssoum sure